Google Cloud "errors":[***"code":"NAME_UNKNOWN","message":"Repository \"us.gcr.io\" not found"
I'm debugging a web app based on Firebase with some Google Cloud functions.
It works fine on localhost but every deploy to Firebase/Google Cloud fails with this error among others:
[2024-04-15T05:07:43.813Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/***/gcf/us-central1/tags/list ***"errors":[***"code":"NAME_UNKNOWN","message":"Repository \"us.gcr.io\" not found"***]***
[2024-04-15T05:07:43.813Z] Failed docker command with error  HTTP Error: 404, Not Found ***"name":"FirebaseError","children":[],"context":***"body":***"errors":[***"code":"NAME_UNKNOWN","message":"Repository \"us.gcr.io\" not found"***],"error":***"message":"Not Found"***,"response":***"statusCode":404***,"exit":1,"message":"HTTP Error: 404, Not Found","status":404***
Gemini suggested some debugging tips but I can't get them to work either:

The error message indicates that the repository us.gcr.io was not found. This could be because the repository does not exist or because you do not have permission to access it.
To resolve this error, you can try the following:
Make sure that the repository us.gcr.io exists. You can do this by running the following command:
gcloud container repositories list


Now distracted from the main error, when I run this command, either from the cloud shell, or from the CLI, I get this error:
gcloud container repositories list

ERROR: (gcloud.container) Invalid choice: 'repositories'.
Maybe you meant:
  gcloud container clusters list
  gcloud container fleet list
  gcloud container hub list
  gcloud container images list
  gcloud container node-pools list
  gcloud container operations list
  gcloud container images list-gcr-usage
  gcloud container images list-tags
  gcloud container subnets list-usable
  gcloud container attached clusters list

To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS

gcloud is up to date. What's causing all of this?
gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 474.0.0
bq 2.1.4
core 2024.04.26
gcloud-crc32c 1.0.0
gsutil 5.27


Quite possibly related to the Container Registry turndown: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have exactly the same issue.. did you solved it ?

No I could not solve the issue.
I switched to Vercel and all issues went away.
The only logical explanation I have right now is that the Firebase support for NextJS is in beta and unexpected issues are anticipated.

I faced a similar problem recently. In my case, the problem was that I was using a local Verdaccio registry for my private dependencies, and I added its local address to .npmrc. Then when I ran npm install, it filled package-lock.json with references to my local Verdaccio registry. When I removed .npmrc, deleted package-lock.json, and ran npm install again, the problem was gone. firebase deploy --only functions --debug did not show any trace of this issue.
(You can host private packages of your project's dependencies on Google Cloud to make your builds work, but I ended up implementing a workaround and did not need to use this feature, so I haven't actually tried it. See: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs#using_private_modules)
Regarding the second part of your question: instead of
gcloud container repositories list
try
gcloud artifacts repositories list --project [your project]
Background: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr
